# How can I know the status of my UK Visa before receiving my Passport

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have applied for UK visitor Visa two weeks ago and I have received this email:

> Your UK visa application has been processed. Please contact TLS at pos.tlscontact.com/kbp_en/index.php/contact if you have not been contacted within the next 2 days regarding return of your documents

Is there anyway to know the decision without having to wait until I receive my passport back?

Comment: Did you apply visa VFS and what country did you apply from?

Comment: @Daniil I have applied through TLS contact center from Hungary.

Comment: From other, alike, questions, likely not.

Comment: No, it means nothing other than they've made a decision. The exact wording appears to vary by office or region, but it doesn't tell you anything. For example I received this message for my own application last week "Your UK visa application has been concluded by Visits UK and will shortly be dispatched." - my application was successful btw.